# Как можно удалить все кроме выбранного шаблона?

Tags: php, javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть большой текст и  regex pattern, Как удалить все и оставить только выбранные, есть ли такой  онлайн ресурс который может сделать это ?

(https://regex101.com/) только выбирает , возможности удалить или скопировать там не нашел.

Если такого ресурса или инструмента  нету тогда  подскажите пожалуйста код на *JavaScript* или *PHP* который может на  основе regex шаблона удалить все кроме выбранных частей.

Comment: А где пример исходного текста и желаемого результата?

Comment: В JavaScript - `.replace`, в PHP - `preg_replace`, C# - `Regex.Replace`.... А в чём проблема-то?

Comment: просто часто встречающаяся задача , сейчас  нужно из большого  HTML кода взять    все id атрибуты , а остальное все удалить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *нужно из большого HTML кода взять все id атрибуты*

```
$big_html = ''; // Ваш HTML

preg_match_all('~id="(.+?)"~', $big_html, $id);

var_dump($id[1]); // Значения всех id
```